# Table view cell custom autolayout issues in XCode 6.1 iOS8

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8, iphone-6-plus

I have a static table view that's designed in the storyboard, and 2 types of cells are used: right detail, and custom.

The reason that I am using custom style is because some cells in my table view need to display UIImage. I am having a hard time lining custom cells up with right detail cell, because right detail cells do not have constraints. I use autolayout for custom cells, you can see the constraint values in the picture. I have a leading space of 7 for custom cells to mimic the leading space for regular right detail cell (Like Status and Gender).

[image: Storyboard setup]

Things mostly work fine until this happened in iPhone 6+ with standard display (In iPhone 6+ you can use either standard or zoom in the display option, the following issue only appears when standard is selected).

[image: Failed to line-up custom cells with right detail cells]

As you can see in the picture, name and profile pictures are both of cell type custom, and their alignment is way off compare to cells below them. I am not sure how to do this properly because putting a fixed value (7 in this case) clearly is a hacky way and does not work in all circumstances. Can someone who is good at autolayouts teach me how to do this properly so that all cells would line up nicely?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Did you managed to solve your question? I face the same issue, not only on the right detail. But the label on the left is also not aligned, e.g. in your Name and Status cells, they are not aligned. How do you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the trailing space constraint with relative to its superview. Refer below screenshot which shows how to add trailing space to its superview.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've added the trailing space but the outcome is still the same. I believe the problem is that the leading space of a right detail table view cell various so no matter what I set (currently 7) it just can't keep up with it on all iPhone resolutions.

Comment: Ya might be, So try like this clear your constraint and then add it manually by using pin option(Second one in my screenshot below)

Comment: But what value should I give to the constraint? It can't be a fixed number because the leading space changes across different screen sizes.

Comment: Yes leading space will be relative to its superview.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Storyboard`, add on your custom cell's representation the `right accessory detail enclosure` "arrow", and then, edit your `constraints` accordingly.

The `right accessory view` is added to the `cell`, so it pushes to the left the `cell's` `contentView`, leading to your alignement issue